# Duffing equation with non-linearity factor greater than unity

Tags: nonlinear-system, perturbation-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

I have been trying to solve the following non-linear equation taking help from the book regarding perturbative technique by H. Nayfeh (chapter -4)

$$\ddot{x}+\frac{x}{(1-x^2)^2}=0$$ where $x<1$ with the initial condition assciated with it such as :

$x(0)=0$ and $\dot{x}(0)=0$.

$x$ and $t$ are two dimensionless parameters such that $x=\frac{y}{D}$ and $t=\omega_0 t$, where $D$ is the charateristic length  and $\omega_0$ is the natural frequency of the system.

Following, chapter-4 as mentioned above, $f(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x^2)^2}$ is analytic at the neighbour of the point $x(0)=x_0=0$ and thus, can be expressed as
$$f(x)=k_1(x-x_0)+k_2(x-x_0)^2+k_3(x-x_0)^3$$

where, $k_1=1$, $k_2=0$ and $k_3=\epsilon=2$. Plugging this in the original equation, I get
$$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+u+\epsilon u^3=0$$
where, $u= x-x_0$
with the initial condition $u(0)=0$ and $\dot{u}(0)=0$
The above equation is a Duffing type equation with non-linearity factor greater than unity but in all the cases, which have been discussed in chapter-4, the non-linearity factor is very small.
I can not understand how to solve this type of equation for both the fast and slow time scales.

Would you kindly suggest me any book or any other source from where I can get some help.

Comment: Why are you reporting at length about the normalization process if you have no question about the normalization? Leave the primes out, it looks at first glance as if you have spacial and time derivatives in the equation. If you do not have an arbitrarily small parameter, you can not apply perturbation theory. You have a conservative system $\ddot x = - V'(x)$ with $V(x)=\frac1{2(1-x^2)}$ so you get periodic solutions for $x\in (-1,1)$ if the velocity is not too large.

Comment: @Lutz, Thanks for your valuable comment...  For large nonlinear factor, perturbation technique can not be applied. Using v dv/dx = V'(x), where v represents velocity and V for potential, a solution may be found out. Is there any other way to get the solution in terms of slow and fast time scale.

Comment: If you explicitly say that you explore solutions with a very small amplitude, then you can set $x=\sqrt\epsilon u$ where $\sqrt\epsilon$ represents the amplitude. Then you  get $\ddot u +\frac{u}{(1-\epsilon u^2)^2}=0$, a non-singular perturbation of the harmonic oscillator.

Comment: @Lutz,Thanks.. okay...that may be helpful..

Comment: @Lutz,Thanks.. okay...that may be helpful....But the primary condition is that the amplitude of the displacement x is smaller than D (or 1 after scaling) but otherwise comparable to D (or 1) i.e to say we can't write $x^2 << D^2$.

Comment: This would give you a large to infinite energy. This would result in a near rectangular closed orbit in phase space. This is closer to singular perturbations than to the regular perturbations that you had considered.